# Тире при пропуске сказуемого

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь ставить тире: *Шеф в тюрьму, а сам в Севастополь*?

Answer (score 1):

Можно ставить, а можно и не ставить. Вот так тоже правильно:
Шеф — в тюрьму, а сам — в Севастополь.

Больше информации [здесь](http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/1946d260-e1a1-4308-8126-72b39aaea09a/punc05.htm).

Answer (score 0):

**Шеф в тюрьму, а сам в Севастополь.**

1) Это предложения **эллиптического типа** (**схема:** подлежащее/дополнение ― обстоятельство). При такой структуре, как в приведенном примере,  тире обычно не ставится (нет паузы).

**Примеры:** Семью в город, **а сам** в Сибирь. [П. П. Бажов. Через межу (1934)]

Жену я уговорил тоже в монастырь в Холмогоры, дочерей туда же, **а сам** в Соловки! [В. И. Немирович-Данченко. Соловки (1874)]

Меня пригласил, **а сам** в сторонку.

2) Тире ставится, если **логически выделено подлежащее**, что соответствует наличию **паузы**.

**Пример:** Это напоминало знаменитый анекдот: «Жене сказал, что пошел к любовнице, любовнице сказал, что пошел к жене, **а сАм** ― в библиотеку». [Герард Васильев. Роли, которые нас выбирают (2002)]